# 401 when authenticating an OAuth 2.0 bearer token with Microsoft Azure Active Directory in an MVC API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, oauth, azure-active-directory, bearer-token

I'm writing an **API service in MVC** (no views, just API), and I want to use **OAuth 2.0 tokens acquired via the client_credentials flow** (2-legged OAuth). I created an **ActiveDirectory app in the Azure management portal**, and have successfully acquired a **bearer token** (see screenshot from Postman at the bottom).

Then I installed the `Microsoft.Owin.Security.ActiveDirectory` nuget package, created an Owin startup class and wrote the following code in it:

```
public class OwinStartup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=316888
        var myoptions = new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions();
        myoptions.Audience = // my App ID
        myoptions.Tenant = // my tenant
        myoptions.AuthenticationMode = Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationMode.Passive;
        app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(myoptions);
    }
}
```

I added a controller with an action, and I would like the action to be accessible with the bearer token.

This is the controller:

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    [Authorize]
    public JsonResult Index()
    {
        return Json(3, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to call it with the Authorization header like this:

[image: Calling endpoint]

However, I'm getting 401: "You do not have permission to view this directory or page". The details are:

```
Module     ManagedPipelineHandler
Notification       ExecuteRequestHandler
Handler    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler
Error Code     0x00000000
Requested URL      http://localhost:57872/test
Logon Method       Anonymous
Logon User     Anonymous
```

It looks that my bearer token is ignored.

What am I doing wrong?

---

**Appendix:** Creating an Azure Active Directory OAuth bearer token in Postman with the client_credentials flow:

[image: Creating a token in Postman]

Answer (score 4):

It seems that I can get it to work by creating a second application in AD - a client app, authorizing it to the service app, and requesting the authentication token as the client rather than as the service.

So in the token request I had to use the client app's ID and secret instead of the original ones and add another parameter: "resource", whose value is the service app ID: `https://mytenant.onmicrosoft.com/servieappname`

I based my solution on [this good example](https://github.com/AzureADSamples/NativeClient-WindowsStore) by Microsoft. Replaced the Windows store app by a web app acting as the client.

Answer (score 1):

I added the following attribute to the controller directing it to use the specific 
authentication filter.

```
[HostAuthentication("Bearer")]
public class someController:ApiController{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your TestController so it derives from ApiController instead of Controller.

Comment: My project was not a WebApi project, so I created a new one and used ApiController instead. The problem persists, only now I'm getting a nice Json response: `{
Message: "Authorization has been denied for this request."
}`

Comment: Hmmm. I made an incorrect assumption about your project - sorry about that.  I'll take another "closer" look.

Comment: Well, I'm having trouble getting my sample to work now.  This OWIN stuff is really a mess right now.  Perhaps we can delete this answer thread and allow someone else to chime in.